# Save/insert image in ms access database

Tags: vb.net

I have a picturebox and two buttons (browse and save image). Once the user click the browse button the user will browse picture from the computer then save it to database by clicking the save button.

Do u have any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Yes, I have a suggestion. Instead to stay here waiting for an answer search for some example, try it and if you still have problems ask again explaining your efforts.

Comment: 92,400 google hits for this on this site alone.  Start your research here: [Ask] then look at the **Related** links on the right (and the related links on those).

Comment: btw. generally, it's not good idea saving image into database (You can, but...). Instead doing that, save image on disk and save it's path into database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, hope it helps:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source = " & Application.StartupPath & "\database.mdb;")
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand

    Dim bytImage() As Byte
    Private Sub Browse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Browse.Click
        Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
        dialog.Title = "Browse Picture"
        dialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG"
        If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
        Try
            Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)

            bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bytImage = ms.ToArray()
            ms.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        cn.Open()
        cm.Connection = cn
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `table` (pic) VALUES (@image)"
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytImage)
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

''---- Save Data In msaccess New accdb msaccess 2007 & Above

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form2
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\acordv.accdb;")
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand

Dim bytImage() As Byte


Private Sub btnbrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnbrowse.Click
    Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
    dialog.Title = "Browse Picture"
    dialog.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG"
    If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Try
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)

        bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        bytImage = ms.ToArray()
        ms.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    cn.Open()
    cm.Connection = cn
    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `pic1` (pic) VALUES (@image)"
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytImage)
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cn.Close()
    MsgBox("Image Saved.")
End Sub
```